# Pointers need on pattern recognition project

Tags: pattern-matching

Hey guys, am doing a final year project, and my aim it to have a system thats able to recognize simple patters, example stripes, polka dots, checked, and plaid (a bit harder). problem is i dont really know here to start. Am not sure which subject area it falls in (am split between neural nets and AI, both of which i will be learn while doing the project). Any ideas as to where is should start, in terms of subject area, programming language etc.

P.S. Thanks in advance for any help/pointers it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project implies that you will probably be doing some AI type learning. LISP and Prolog have traditionally been used in such applications.

I don't know if you have to use neural nets but if you do, then ideally you want to see if you can find a good library for them and then pick the language that best meets your skills and allows you to use the library =)

Regarding the subject matter, your prof. is probably the best person to ask for starting points.

PS: Neural nets are not too hard to implement manually either, I used a simple one for my project which was in C++.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Super Thanks vic!, i am familiar with Prolog... how ever i dont have a clue how Prolog will read and process a image file, but that will be all part of the learning process. And unfortunately i do not have a professor that specialize in this subject, although the foundations of it is taught in class.

Answer (score 0):

To discern among stripes, polka dots, etc., I would suggest building a classifier based on simple image statistics.  The classifier could be any of a large number of things (neural network, linear discriminant, quadratic discriminant, blah blah), but I'd expect any of them to work reasonably well.  Hence, I suggest looking for tools to build classifiers in the languages or tools you already know.